# Usar React sin Node.js

Tags: django, nodejs, reactjs

estoy iniciándome en esto de React. Por lo que estoy viendo no hay otra forma de usar React que no sea escribiéndolo en JSX y luego compilarlo con Babel para que funcione. Pero para poder usar Babel desde consola tengo que usar Node.js. Sino la única que me queda es usar Babel desde la [web](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=latest%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D.map(n%20%3D%3E%20n%20%2B%201)%3B&playground=true), pero claramente este método no es para nada práctico. Yo estoy usando Django para el lado del servidor, por lo que no quiero tener que empezar a implementar código del lado del server en Node. Solo usarlo para el `frontend`. ¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo?

Comment: Solo para clarificar, si estás desarrollando tanto el _frontend_ como el _backend_, puede parecer que necesitas NodeJS del lado del servidor, pero no es así en realidad. Piensa que solo desarrollas el _frontend_, necesitas NodeJS **para el desarrollo**. Una vez que tu _frontend_ está en producción, **no necesitas NodeJS**. Usar `Babel` desde la web, puede parecer lento, pero **solo se usa en desarrollo**.

Comment: Gracias por responder! Exactamente como decís vos, se usa en desarrollo, pero como solo es posible ver los resultados con el código compilado era medio tedioso tener que compilar cada vez que se efectuaba un cambio. Con la respuesta de abajo ya se compila automáticamente. Después en producción lo compilare para mejor performance

Comment: Si usas `gulp` o `grunt` puedes vigilar los cambios... incluso usando el _transpilador_ de la CDN, puedes usar `lite-server` para ver los cambios de inmediato.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para usar JSX, sí es necesario usar un *Transpiler* como *Babel*, la mejor solución para no usar *Node* sería usar *babel-standalone* vía el *CDN*. Hacer tus scripts por separado y cargarlos. *babel-standalone* te ofrece las herramientas para compilarlo en línea.

Si no quieres usar el *CDN*, podrías crear una pequeña instalación de *Node* en tu máquina local, usar *Webpack* o *babel-cli* para compilar el JSX y subirlo a tu servidor.

Aquí puedes encontrar más información sobre [*babel-standalone*.](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Justo lo que buscaba!

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres evitar la configuracion con babel y web pack y empezar lo mas rapido con el fron end te recomiendo `react-create-app`es el cli recomendado por el equipo de facebook para empezar tu front end sin meterte con node, babel y webpack, ya es ta todo configurado para que empiezes a programar con react.

Esta aplicacion se deberia comunicar con tu back en `Django` atra vez de servicio haciendo peticiones http desde el front al back para obtener la informacion que necesites.

`react-create-app` tiene un comando para hacer le buil de tu proyecto `npm run build` y lo puedes subir facilmente a tu host como heroku aws etc.

Comment: No estaba enterado! Gracias por la info y responder! Muy buena herramienta!